# How to save a video canny edge python?

Tags: javascript

I am experimenting with canny edge detection with the webcam. The code works fine for me.
But I want to save the videos recorded by the cam in canny edge. In some format to save .mp4, .avi, etc..?
What code would I have to add more to save the video from the cam?

CODE USED PYTHON:

import cv2

import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

## loop runs if capturing has been initialized

while 1:

```
ret, frame = cap.read() 

# converting BGR to HSV 
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) 
  
# define range of red color in HSV 
lower_red = np.array([5,50,50]) 
upper_red = np.array([15,255,255]) 
  
# create a red HSV colour boundary and  
# threshold HSV image 
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red) 

# Bitwise-AND mask and original image 
res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask) 

# Display an original image 
cv2.imshow('Original',frame) 

# finds edges in the input image image and 
# marks them in the output map edges 
edges = cv2.Canny(frame,100,200) 

# Display edges in a frame 
cv2.imshow('Edges',edges) 

# Wait for Esc key to stop 
k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
if k == 27: 
    break
```

## Close the window

cap.release()

## De-allocate any associated memory usage

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

What code do I use to save my cam recordings in canny edge? Thank you